# Consulta en mysql de varias tablas (Lista de clientes tratados por tal doctor)

Tags: mysql, sql

ahora vengo con un problema más el cual no se como hacerle para continuar intente unirla con inner join pero no me salio.

Tengo varias tablas: facturas, detalle_factura, clientes, productos, médicos, el cuál quiero consultar una lista de todos los clientes(pacientes) que hayan sido tratados por tal doctor. pero no se como generar la consulta.

**Si me pueden ayudar por favor se los super agradecería.**

Quiero que aparezca la lista de todos los clientes por x doctor y que aparezca así en la tabla:

#numero_factura  (tabla factura)| nombre_cliente  (tabla cliente)| Estudios que se realizo  (tabla productos)| fecha_factura  (tabla factura)| atendio (tabla users) | estatus (tabla factura)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No veo por ninguna parte el campo atendio de la tabla user

Comment: Podrías compartir la consulta que no te funciona para poder identificar el error.

Comment: japv si perdón el de atendió seria el nombre del usuario de la tabla user que hace función del vendedor.

Comment: Francisco tengo esto donde ya lo recorte select * from facturas f, clientes c WHERE f.id_medico = '3' and f.id_cliente = c.id_cliente y me arroja los clientes que tiene el medico solo me faltaria los demas datos que en eso ando averiguando

Comment: ¿Ninguna de tus *FK* esta relacionada a ninguna de tus *Pk*, ni en `users`, `clientes` o `medicos`?

Answer (score 0):

Si querés presentar datos de múltiples tablas tenés que relacionar todas las tablas de las que querés obtener datos.
Realizar INNER JOIN entre clientes y facturas y seleccionar aquellos resultados que tengan id_medico requerido (cláusula WHERE). A su vez en otro INNER JOIN seleccionar los detalles de dichas facturas, y para finalizar otro INNER JOIN para obtener los productos que correspondan con cada detalle.
Yo seleccioné id_vendedor de la factura, pero podrías buscar el nombre del user con otro INNER JOIN.

Te recomendaría revisar tus atributos claves. Por ejemplo en clientes no encuentro sentido a que haya un id_cliente clave y también el nombre sea clave.

Podrías usar patrón OID si querés que la capa de persistencia no conozca las reglas del negocio, en otro caso recomiendo utilizar atributos del negocio como clave, pero no mezclar claves ID con atributos de negocio, porque esto no tiene sentido.

Te recomiendo revisar la normalización de tu modelo y dejarlo en un punto óptimo para lo que necesites.

```
SELECT numero_factura, 
               nombre_cliente, 
               nombre_producto,
               fecha_factura,
               id_vendedor,
               estatus
FROM clientes 
INNER JOIN facturas 
      ON clientes.id_cliente =
      facturas.id_cliente
INNER JOIN detalle_factura
      ON detalle_factura.numero_factura =
      facturas.numero_factura
INNER JOIN productos 
      ON detalle_factura.id_producto =
      productos.id_producto
WHERE id_medico = 4;
```

La complejidad que has agregado a tu modelo por la elección de claves, está complejizando tus consultas innecesariamente.